# Can't pass through the Moonson boss fight?

Tags: metal-gear-rising-revengeance

When I have Moonson at 10% I can jump on the pyramid he throws at me but then how can I duck the tank? I have seen solutions to cut through the tank but how does it work? I have tried every key but Jack isn't cutting through the tank? I'm using the PC version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cut the APC by going into blade mode (left trigger on the default Xbox 360 gamepad setup) and pressing the light attack button (X, for me) when aimed at the APC.

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OddVmAd_zE8&t=6m20s)'s a video of it.